# Pitfalls of using random forest/GBM on proportion data?

Tags: random-forest, proportion, boosting

I have a set of data with a dependent variable which represents a proportion, and many of the samples contain a response of 1.  I would like to build a random forest or GBM regression model on the data, with my main concern being the out of sample performance of E[y|x].  Are there any pitfalls to simply minimizing a squared error cost function over proportion data?

Comment: Have you tried logistic regression?

Comment: Do you mean applying a logistic transformation before performing regression?  It doesn't seem like a satisfactory solution to me (how to handle 0s and 1s, etc).  If you mean logistic regression in the conventional sense, then no, because I am trying to regress proportions instead of estimating probabilities.

Comment: I mean in the conventional sense. There's no requirement that you be calculating probabilities, it's just the most common use because the result is restricted to the range 0 to 1 - which is exactly what you want.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'd like to use RF/GBM models specifically because there are many nonlinearities and interactions in my dataset.  As far as I know using log loss with R's GBM package requires binary inputs ...